# hyper-v availability group

Tags: hyper-v, groups

We are setting up SQL AG's (availability groups) on Hyper-V. We want to use SQL Server for HA and DR. IE:- We want SQL Server to perform failovers between SQL replicas, we don't want SQL and Hyper-V trying to failover at the same time.

I'm not familiar with Hyper-V so excude my ignorance, but how to I configure a SQL Server VM to NOT startup after the node it is running on Fails?

Eg:- 
Primary   replica on Node-1, 
Secondary replica on Node-2.
Node-3 is non-SQL
If Node-1 fails, I want SQL to failover to Node-3 (It can't failover to Node-2 due to anti-affinity rules)
Monitoring will raise an alert. We then migrate the previous primary replica running on Node-2 to Node-3. 
When Node-1 is available, we migrate back.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> but how to I configure a SQL Server VM to NOT startup after the node it is running on 
>   Fails?

Why do you care? This isa situation a HA AG in SQL Server has to ahndle - what if you do not use vm's but 2 servers and one gets a second long power outage and then restarts?

As long as both VM's are on 2 physical machines (i.e. Hyper-V nodes) this is not a situation that should bother you at all.

If properly set up, you will get Hyper-V restarting the node and SQL Server failing over, but both will not fall back and the server should work without any issues anyway.

That means that in this case you issue is a non-issue and the only answer is not to care.

Alternatively you do not set up the Hyper-V part on an availability group. Not sure that 2 SQL AG instances on ONE PIECE OF CLUSTER make any sense - I would prefer anything larger in hardware with very well planned disc storage.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We have 4 cluster nodes. I don't want SQL Server potentially failing over at the same time as Hyper-V fails over. Due to node /network utilisation/storage utilisation etc, each could interfere with the other, this would make troubleshooting/diagnostics more difficult. I think its better to simply let SQL Server handle the failover to the secondary replica.. We can then migrate the failed original primary to another node (so we one agaian have a HA pair) - Note we have a ASYNC replica in another data centre.

Comment: Seriously, if you have problems with this your network is TREMENDOUSLY too small to handle the load of a proper SQL Serer to start with.